# What icons required for app to submit to MAC App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store

Does anyone know of what size icons do I need to have in my binary to submit it to MAC App Store. Is there a special key under which I need to mention it or can I just include in Resources folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is a moving target. Recommend going to Apple developer site for the latest updates in the maze of icon sizes...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: That link is for iOS, but the question was about the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

The full set required for application submission, for ipad and phone is much more extensive - with the new retina displays etc.

1. 1024
2. 512
3. 144
4. 114
5. 72
6. 57

Many things have changed in the last year - they will continue - its a moving target - I would use the developer guidelines. The design is evolving towards greater simplicity with regard to borders, highlights and shadows. As a designer, you have more control. The greatest challenge is to make an emotional connection in this little space.

Answer (score 0):

According to iTunes User Guide your MAC application should have 512x512 and a 128x128 image in your binary.