# Mac App store icon sizes (plist requirements)

Tags: macos

I'm having a really tough time trying to find out the icon size requirements for the mac app store and how to set these up in the plist. Could someone please list these for me?

I tried looking at Apple's docs but they keep directing me towards iOS which adds to my confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907194/what-icons-required-for-app-to-submit-to-mac-app-store

Comment: I think the requirements have changed with retina displays and I've also had trouble with knowing how to set the plist to accommodate this.